# ASP.NET MVC 3 Error: 'ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailable' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run an ASP.NET MVC 3 project:

'ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailable' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment. This API requires that the calling application be hosted in IIS or WAS.

When I run the project through Visual Studio 2010 by hitting F5, it loads up just fine. I only get this error when trying to access the application through http://localhost/projectname. What's strange is that this code base worked on my computer before I formatted and reinstalled Windows on it. Any idea what this error message means?

Here's the stack trace if it helps at all:

[InvalidOperationException: 'ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailable' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment. This API requires that the calling application be hosted in IIS or WAS.]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized() +378
   System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state) +106
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.BeginProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +175
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +115
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371

**UPDATE**: I went ahead and created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using Visual Studio 2010's templates. I added the application to IIS and tried to access it and received the same error. I'm thinking there may be something wrong with my IIS installation.

Comment: Are you using WCF inside your MVC project?

Comment: Yes, I added a Service Reference to a web service using WCF.

Comment: But is this WCF service hosted in the same site as your ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: No. This is a third party WCF service that I added a reference to in my project. My project does not expose any web services.

Comment: Where is this service hosted? IIS?

Comment: Yes, I'm running IIS7 on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You might check the [following blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/09/22/wcf-rest-services-inside-mvc-projects.aspx).</strike>

---

UPDATE:

The problem seems to be related to the installation of .NET 4.0. Reinstalling it fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes, I've read through that post. I haven't tweaked with my routes at all (I'm simply using the default ones provided by ASP.NET MVC 3) and I'm not hosting my own WCF services so I'm not sure what to do with the findings of that post.

Comment: @Kevin, when you say that you are hosting the web service on your own do you mean a console application or a Windows NT Service?

Comment: It's safe to ignore the fact that I'm using a web service. I created a completely new ASP.NET MVC 3 project from scratch and it also gets that same error when I try to load it up.

Comment: @Kevin in your update you mentioned that you used VS2008 to create an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. Did you mean VS2010?

Comment: How are you deploying your application on IIS? Are you using the Publish functionality in VS2010 or are you running it directly? Is the application in IIS properly configured? Is it using .NET 4.0? Classic or Integrated mode?

Comment: I'm simply building the project. I added the application under IIS and am navigating to the virtual path (e.g. http://localhost/applicationname). Yes, it's using .NET 4.0 and it's using integrated mode in the application pool.

Comment: @Kevin, try using a normal ASP.NET application, not MVC.

Comment: Just created an ASP.NET web forms application and I'm getting the same error. It looks like it's related to IIS somehow. Maybe I'll remove IIS and add it back and see what happens.

Comment: @Kevin, yes I think there is some problem with your IIS and/or .NET 4.0 installation. Try reinstalling those components.

Comment: You were right. I reinstalled .NET 4.0 and everything works like a charm. Thanks! :-)